# Grails hasMany delete behavior

Tags: grails, grails-orm, cascade

I have 2 domain classes

```
class A {
   static hasMany = [ b : B ]
}

class B {
   static belongsTo = A
}
```

I would like to keep the cascading saves, so when I save A, it updates the B's, but when I do a delete of A, I would like it to fail if any B's exist that are associated with that A. So you would have to explicitly delete all of the B's first.

I'm not sure the easiest way to do this in Grails. I could put a check in A before I delete it to verify that there are no B's - simple enough. But is there a way to control this through cascading or relationship behaviors so I don't have to put the logic in there?

Comment: I think the question is answered here: http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/ by Peter Ledbrook

Comment: I had read that, and I'm not sure it answers it (it's a long article, so it's possible I missed it). It's not clear how to disable cascading deletes, but still keep the bi-directional association. `B` cannot exist without an `A` in my case, but I want to fail if a user tries to delete an `A` without first deleting the `B`s - I don't automatically want to delete the `B`s

Comment: ah lads - naming!.  Why use A and B, when you could use Dog and Leg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the cascade behavior for the collection

```
class A {
   static hasMany = [ b : B ]

   static mapping = {
        b cascade: 'save-update'
    }
}
```

It will cascade save and update but not delete.

Comment: If I try to delete A, this will fail with a foreign key constraint, correct?

Comment: Yes, Try it it wont let you delete